# im trying to link my arduino data into my speedometer widget in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Im trying to link my arduino speed data to my speedometer on kivy. For example, when my speed in the arduino serial monitor is 20.5, i want the needle of my speedometer to point at that value(angle). Right now, i just set the needle to go from left(-90 deg) to right(90 deg) continuously.

Arduino serial monitor
[image: Arduino serial monitor]

Speedometer needle moving from -90deg to 90 deg
[image: Speedometer needle moving from -90deg to 90 deg]

.py file

```
import threading    
import serial
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.app import App

class SpeedWindow(Screen):
    speed_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SpeedWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        threading.Thread(target=self.tm).start()

    def tm(self):
        while (1):
            with serial.Serial('COM4', 9600) as ser:
                value = ser.readline()
                ser.close()
                self.update_fix(value.decode('utf-8'))

    @mainthread
    def update_fix(self, value):
        self.speed_text = value

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

KV = """

WindowManager:
    SpeedWindow:

<SpeedWindow>:
    angle: 90    
    name: 'speedometer'   

    Image:
        source: 'cadran.png'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 400, 400
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

    Image:
        source: 'needle.png'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 170, 170
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}   
        # apply rotation matrix to this Image                                                                                                                                            
        canvas.before:                                                                                                                                             
            PushMatrix                                                                                                                                             
            Rotate:                                                                                                                                                
                angle: root.angle                                                                                                                                  
                axis: (0, 0, 1)                                                                                                                                    
                origin: (self.center_x, self.center_y , 0)                                                                                                                              
        canvas.after:                                                                                                                                              
            PopMatrix                           
"""

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.animate_needle, 1.0)  # start the animation in 2 seconds
        return  Builder.load_string(KV)

    def animate_needle(self, dt):
        # animate the needle from +90 to -90 and then back to +90
        self.anim = Animation(angle=-90.0) + Animation(angle=90)
        self.anim.repeat = True    # repeat forever
        speedometer = self.root.get_screen('speedometer')
        self.anim.start(speedometer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just remove the `animate_needle()` method and change your `update_fix()` method to calculate an appropriate angle:

```
@mainthread
def update_fix(self, value):
    self.speed_text = value
    self.angle = 90.0 - 180.0 * float(value)/100.0
```

The formula simply gives `90` when the value is `0` and `-90` when the value is `100`, and interpolates in between.